# Develop Flask without need to restart application

Tags: flask

I try to use Flask to make a small app but the constant need to restart the application to see the results is an overkill.

Is there any setup that will simply update the application without restarts? (Similar to any decent PHP or Java/JSP application)

[Edit]
The restart of the application can be manual or automatic by setting the flag debug to True.
In both cases the application is restarted. I'm interested in a no start/restart of the application - not manually or automatic.

The best example is a PHP page where you do not not have to restart whole server just to see the changes.

Comment: set `debug=True`

Answer (score 1):

```
app = Flask(__name__)
...
app.run(debug=True)
```

Don't use `debug = True` in production.

Comment: debug == True simply instruct the engine to restart itself. It does not eliminate the restart.